# full calendar - passing event data from observable - not showing up on calendar

Tags: angular, rxjs, fullcalendar, observable, behaviorsubject

I am using ap-fullcalendar for angular/typescript. I have a data service, where I get the events for the calendar from my database, I wrap the data in a Behaviour Subject and subscribe to it and make it into an observable from another function. I have a data service because I have multiple subscriptions to the same observable. In my component where the calendar is, I subscribe to the data. However, for some reason, the events are not getting passed properly to the calendar and won't show up. I have manually entered some values for events, to check the calendar works fine, which it does. I have outputted what I get from my service (shown below) and it looks fine. What could the issue be?

Data service:

```
@Injectable()
export class SubjectEventsService {

  allData: EventSchema[] = new Array<EventSchema>();
  allData$: BehaviorSubject<EventSchema[]>;


  constructor(private afs : AngularFirestore) { 
    //Get subjectEvents collection on initialise
    this.subjectEventCollection = this.afs.collection('subjectEvents');
    this.getSubjectEvents();
  }


  getSubjectEvents(subjectFilter?:string){
    if(!this.allData$){
      this.allData$ = <BehaviorSubject<EventSchema[]>> new BehaviorSubject(new Array<EventSchema>());
      this.subjectEventCollection.valueChanges().pipe(
        map(res => {
          let result : EventSchema[] = [];
          res.map(subjectEvent => {
            let eventSchema : EventSchema[] = subjectEvent.eventData;
            eventSchema.forEach(event => {
              result.push(event as EventSchema);
            })
          })
          console.log(result);
          return result;
        }))
        .subscribe(events => {
          console.log(events);
          this.allData = events;
          console.log(this.allData);
          this.allData$.next(events);
        });
      }
    }

  subscribeToDataServiceGetSubjectEvents(): Observable<EventSchema[]> {
    console.log(this.allData$);
    return this.allData$.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Home component (where calendar is):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit{

  calendarOptions: any;
  displayEvent: any;
  @ViewChild(CalendarComponent) ucCalendar: CalendarComponent;
  name: string;
  subjectFilter: string;

  allData$: Observable<EventSchema[]>;

  constructor(private subjectEventsService: SubjectEventsService, private dialog: MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.subjectEventsService.subscribeToDataServiceGetSubjectEvents().subscribe(data=>{
      let data$:any = data;
      console.log("fun");
      console.log(data);
      this.calendarOptions = {
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: false,
        header: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
        },
        events: data$,
        //WORKS FINE WITH THIS DATA ENTERED MANUALLY
        // [{
        //   end: "2018-08-13T19:00:00",
        //   price: 10,          
        //   start:"2018-08-13T17:00:00",
        //   title:"Forces"
        // }],
        eventClick: (calEvent, jsEvent, view) => {
          this.openDialog(calEvent);
          // console.log('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
          // console.log('View: ' + view.name);
        }
      };
    });    
  }
  }
}
```

Output from subscribe (this is an acceptable format required by the calendar):

```
Array(4)
0:{end: "2018-08-13T19:00:00", price: 10, start: "2018-08-13T17:00:00", title: "Forces"}
1:{end: "2018-08-19T13:00:00", price: 10, start: "2018-08-19T11:00:00", title: "Energy"}
2:{end: "2018-08-15T20:00:00", price: 10, start: "2018-08-15T17:00:00", title: "Trigonometry"}
3:{end: "2018-08-25T11:00:00", price: 10, start: "2018-08-25T08:00:00", title: "Mechanics"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way this appears to work is calling through the ViewChild.  The two key parts of this are `this.calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents');` and `this.calendar.fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);` in your subscription, so in your instance, something like this should work:

```js
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-home',
      templateUrl: './home.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
    })
    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit{

        calendarOptions:Object = {
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: false,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
            },
            events: [],
            eventClick: (calEvent, jsEvent, view) => {
                this.openDialog(calEvent);
            }
        };
      displayEvent: any;
      @ViewChild(CalendarComponent) ucCalendar: CalendarComponent;
      name: string;
      subjectFilter: string;

      allData$: Observable<EventSchema[]>;

      constructor(private subjectEventsService: SubjectEventsService, private dialog: MatDialog) { }

      ngOnInit(){
        this.subjectEventsService.subscribeToDataServiceGetSubjectEvents().subscribe(data=>{
          this.ucCalendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents');
          this.ucCalendar.fullCalendar('addEventSource', data);
        });    
      }
      }
    }
```

#### My test project (for sanity)

---

```js
    export class CalComponent implements OnInit {
      @ViewChild('calendar') calendar;

      _events = new BehaviorSubject<Event[]>(EVENTS);
      events$ = this._events.asObservable();

      constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

      onCalendarInit(e:boolean) {
        if(e) {
          this.events$.subscribe((events) => {
            this.calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents');
            this.calendar.fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);
          });
        }
      }

      count:number = 1;
      nextEvent() {
        this.count++;
        EVENTS.push({id: 10 + this.count, title: "Hello!", start: `2018-08-${this.count}`});
        this._events.next(EVENTS);
      }

      calendarOptions:Object = {
        height: '600px',
        fixedWeekCount : false,
        defaultDate: '2016-09-12',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true,
        events: [] //Nothing needed here
      };
    }

    interface Event {
      id?:number;
      title:string;
      start:string;
      end?:string;
    }
```

Html

```html
    <button (click)="nextEvent()">Click for next event</button>
    <angular2-fullcalendar #calendar [options]="calendarOptions" (initialized)="onCalendarInit($event)"></angular2-fullcalendar>
```

[More Info](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-data)

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out and let you know! Its weird, because before I made a change to use Behaviour Subject, I was still subscribing and getting the data in the same format. Not sure why its different this time.

Comment: There were a couple other ways that would initialize with values, but not update without a refresh.  This was the only way I could find to get it to update live.

Comment: Ahh I understand. This worked great, thanks. I will put this as the correct answer.